# extract element where certain unicode string is

Tags: php, unicode

ok i've done some search on the questions. I couldn't find any solution.
Here is the thing. I've some paragraphs with Unicode texts. I want to extract all the characters from a certain paragraph where certain string exist.

```
$paragraphs = "<p>ареги: сейчас на Десятую, Международную, Конференцию, по</p>
       <p>которая состоится: 10-12 марта 1997 года в Майнце в Германии</p>
       <p>Конференция соберет: широкий круг экспертов по  вопросам глобального</p>
       <p>Интернета: и Unicode, локализации и интернационализации, воплощению</p>
       <p>жениях: шрифтах, верстке и многоязычных компьютерных системах</p>";
```

Lets just say that i want the content of paragraph which contains the Unicode string **ареги:** which you can see in the first paragraph.

In that case my result should be

```
ареги: сейчас на Десятую, Международную, Конференцию, по
```

**I prefer PHP.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified where the datasource for your paragraphs is, so here's one way you can achieve this using a pre-defined array (for example):

```
<?php

// Data Source
$paragraphs = array(
    '<p>ареги: сейчас на Десятую, Международную, Конференцию, по</p>',
    '<p>которая состоится: 10-12 марта 1997 года в Майнце в Германии</p>',
    '<p>Конференция соберет: широкий круг экспертов по  вопросам глобального</p>',
    '<p>Интернета: и Unicode, локализации и интернационализации, воплощению</p>',
    '<p>жениях: шрифтах, верстке и многоязычных компьютерных системах</p>'
);

// Search Function
function search($term, $paragraphs = array()) {
    foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
        if (preg_match('/'. $term .'/', $paragraph)) {
            return $paragraph;
        }
    }
    return '';
}

// Usage
echo search('ареги', $paragraphs);

?>
```

**Edit v2 :** 
Here's an alternate version of the above, if the data source is a single line of html paragraphs:

```
<?php

// Data Source
$paragraphs = '<p>ареги: сейчас на Десятую, Международную, Конференцию, по</p>
   <p>которая состоится: 10-12 марта 1997 года в Майнце в Германии</p>
   <p>Конференция соберет: широкий круг экспертов по  вопросам глобального</p>
   <p>Интернета: и Unicode, локализации и интернационализации, воплощению</p>
   <p>жениях: шрифтах, верстке и многоязычных компьютерных системах</p>';

// Search Function
function search($term, $paragraphs) {
    $paragraphs = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $paragraphs);
    $paragraphs = explode('</p> <p>', $paragraphs);
    array_walk_recursive($paragraphs, function(&$para) {
        $para = trim($para);
        $para = str_replace(array('<p>', '</p>'), '', $para);
    });
    foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
        if (preg_match('/'. $term .'/', $paragraph)) {
            return $paragraph;
        }
    }
    return '';
}

// Usage
echo search('ареги', $paragraphs);

?>
```

Comment: The second one i good. But it is removing spaces. like say if we search Интернета: ( the 4th paragraph). the result is Интернета:иUnicode,локализациииинтернационализации,воплощению. Notice the missing spaces?

Comment: It ruined the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `strpos()` or `mb_strpos()`

If it doesn't work for you then you have to make sure your input is unicode.

Little example:

```
$paragraphs = '
    <p>ареги: сейчас на Десятую, Международную, Конференцию, по</p>
    <p>которая состоится: 10-12 марта 1997 года в Майнце в Германии</p>
    <p>Конференция соберет: широкий круг экспертов по  вопросам глобального</p>
    <p>Интернета: и Unicode, локализации и интернационализации, воплощению</p>
    <p>жениях: шрифтах, верстке и многоязычных компьютерных системах</p>
';

$pos = strpos( $paragraphs, 'ареги' );

if( $pos === false )
    echo 'not found';
else
    echo 'found';
```

Comment: No he can't use both `strpos()` and `mb_strpos()`. He can only use `mb_strpos()` for that